# Showing three lines have a common intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

Do the three lines $2x+3y=-1$,$6x+5y=0$, and $2x-5y=7$ have a common point of intersection.

For this question I made a augmented matrix.

My matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
2&3&-1\\
6&5&0 \\
2&-5&7
\end{bmatrix}

But I cannot figure out a way to solve it its as if there 2 variables and 3 equations.

Unless two variable equal each other somehow.

Comment: The first row should be $2 ,3 ,-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2x+3y=-1$,$6x+5y=0$, $2x-5y=7$

First two equations give $x=\frac58,y=-\frac34$ putting these in last equation we see $2\times \frac58 +5\times \frac34=5\ne7$

Comment: So x=5/8 and y=-3/4 will not work for all the system therefore the system is not consistent.

Comment: Correct.Thus these lines have no common point of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Three equations and two unknowns no.. not that at all. If you solve first two, the solution you get must be the same as when you solve last two for a concurrency condition, else there is no common meeting point.

If $ a x + b y + c = 0 $ and $  A x + B y + C = 0,$ then $( a x + b y + c) + k ( A x + B y + C ) = 0 $ also, (k real constant) for a common meeting point.

Three concurrent lines or a "pencil of lines" seem to rotate about a shared point of intersection. The third is obtained by adding zeros of left hand side equations multiplied with k. It is fun if you graph them together. The technique of combining equations will help in future with curves also.